# Unable to load library in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jna

I have a 3rd party native library (let's call it **test.dylib**) which I am trying to load through JNA in a Maven project.
output of **otool -L test.dylib** is

```
/Library/Frameworks/test/Versions/A/test (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)

   /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 19.0.0)

   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 945.11.0)

   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)

   /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 65.1.0)

   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)

   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 744.1.0)
```

If I paste the test.dylib file at location **"/Library/Frameworks/test/Versions/A/test "** from otool -L output.
And load the file through JNA, it works fine. But if I keep the test.dylib under resource folder, I get error.

java.io.IOException: Native library (darwin-x86-64/test.dylib) not found in resource path (/Users/username/Downloads/TestJNA/target/classes:

Even though I can see the dylib file present in /target/classes folder. Can someone suggest, how can I achieve calling dylib from resource folder? I don't want to paste the dylib file at this location "/Library/Frameworks/test/Versions/A/test".

This is how I am loading native library.

```
public class TestJNA {

     public interface Perception extends Library {
          Perception Instance = (Perception) Native.load("test",  Perception.class);

          void method1();
           int method2(int a, int b, int c);
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
           Perception.Instance.method1();
           System.out.println(Perception.Instance.method2(1,2,3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `jna.library.path` to the path to the dll?

Comment: @DanielWiddis Yes. I did try setting jna.library.path programmatically to the location where i have dylib 
System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "/Users/username/Downloads/TestJNA/src/main/java");
dylib absolute path is "/Users/username/Downloads/TestJNA/src/main/java/test.dylib"

Answer (score 2):

While the error message you received only lists one search path, JNA actually checks multiple locations for your library.  As documented in the [NativeLibrary class javadocs](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.11.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html):

> A search for a given library will scan the following locations:
>
> 1. `jna.library.path` User-customizable path
> 2. `jna.platform.library.path` Platform-specific paths
> 3. On OSX, `~/Library/Frameworks`, `/Library/Frameworks`, and `/System/Library/Frameworks` will be searched for a framework with a
>    name corresponding to that requested. Absolute paths to frameworks are
>    also accepted, either ending at the framework name (sans ".framework")
>    or the full path to the framework shared library (e.g.
>    CoreServices.framework/CoreServices).
> 4. Context class loader classpath. Deployed native libraries may be installed on the classpath under `${os-prefix}/LIBRARY_FILENAME`,
>    where `${os-prefix}` is the OS/Arch prefix returned by
>    `Platform.getNativeLibraryResourcePrefix()`. If bundled in a jar file,
>    the resource will be extracted to `jna.tmpdir` for loading, and later
>    removed (but only if `jna.nounpack` is false or not set).
>
> You may set the system property `jna.debug_load=true` to make JNA
> print the steps of its library search to the console.

Note the `os-prefix` directory in item 4 above.  You have included your library directly on the classpath (from the comments, `/Users/username/Downloads/TestJNA/src/main/java/test.dylib`).  However, as the error message states, it needs to be in the `darwin-x86-64/` directory on your classpath, e.g., `/Users/username/Downloads/TestJNA/src/main/java/darwin-x86-64/test.dylib`;

You may wish to use `src/main/resources` in preference to the `java` subdirectory for non-java code.

Your attempt to set the system library path to your raw source code directory doesn't work for the compiled code where it is looking in the `target/classes` directory structure.

Note that you can get further debugging information by setting the system property `jna.debug_load=true`.